# Migrate MBR/BIOS RAID 1 root partition to GPT/UEFI with LVM

Tags: uefi, raid, lvm

I have been pondering this for a while, and searching various posts, but can't find something that is aligned with my situation.

I am running 18.04.3 LTS currently on a couple of SSDs in RAID 1 (along with a separate data RAID 6, with LVM, on a bunch of HDDs). I set this up a number of years ago (with 14.04 LTS at the time) when my motherboard supported only MBR/BIOS.

Since then I have upgraded the motherboard to one supporting UEFI. I am now at the point of upgrading the SSDs as well (larger M.2 units).

Rather than just replace the SSDs while maintaining the current setup, I've been thinking about:

- changing the setup to GPT/UEFI, and
- installing LVM on top of the RAID 1.

I am trying to work out the best way of doing either or both of the above. I've contemplated just doing a completely fresh install on the new SSDs (this has it's attractions as a means of getting rid of cruft accumulated over the years), but I shudder at the thought of reconfiguring everything (there is a lot...).

Is there another way?

In terms of migrating to GPT/UEFI, I've looked at the possibility of doing it *in situ* with something like `Boot-Repair`. Another option I have contemplated is partitioning the new SSDs with the scheme that I want (simply EFI boot partition and root partition), and then introducing them in turn to the array - a little like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1146652/trying-to-move-from-mbr-to-gpt-raid1-and-grub-wont-start).

But I am not entirely clear whether either would work, eg can `Boot-Repair` modify a live system without destroying data (and would inserting an EFI boot partition at the start of the disks upset `mdadm`), and how do I install the EFI bootloader on a manually created EFI boot partition if I am not reinstalling the OS?

As to the question of installing LVM over the existing RAID 1, I am struggling to think how that would be achieved.

Some current setup (as far as relevant - I have removed superfluous info) for further context:

```
$ cat /proc/mdstat

md1 : active raid1 sdg5[2] sdh5[3]
      16757632 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
      
md0 : active raid1 sdg1[2] sdh1[3]
      100386688 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
```

And:

```
$ sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sdg: 111.8 GiB, 120034123776 bytes, 234441648 sectors                                                                                                                                         
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes                                                                                                                                                                   
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes                                                                                                                                                   
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes                                                                                                                                                       
Disklabel type: dos                                                                                                                                                                                     
Disk identifier: 0x0001cb75                                                                                                                                                                             
                                                                                                                                                                                                        
Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type                                                                                                                                             
/dev/sdg1  *         2048 200906751 200904704 95.8G fd Linux RAID autodetect                                                                                                                            
/dev/sdg2       200908798 234440703  33531906   16G  5 Extended                                                                                                                                         
/dev/sdg5       200908800 234440703  33531904   16G fd Linux RAID autodetect                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
Disk /dev/sdh: 111.8 GiB, 120034123776 bytes, 234441648 sectors                                                                                                                                         
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes                                                                                                                                                                   
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes                                                                                                                                                   
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes                                                                                                                                                       
Disklabel type: dos
Disklabel type: dos                                                                                                                                                                                     
Disk identifier: 0x0001cb75

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdh1  *         2048 200906751 200904704 95.8G fd Linux RAID autodetect
/dev/sdh2       200908798 234440703  33531906   16G  5 Extended
/dev/sdh5       200908800 234440703  33531904   16G fd Linux RAID autodetect
```

`/dev/md0` is mount on root (ext4), and `/dev/md1` is assigned as the swap partition.

If I was able to transition the system to LVM, I would do away with the physical swap partition and just create an LVM swap partition. I suppose that might also help with the migration process as it would free up some space on the current SSDs.

Any thoughts? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I managed to finalise this migration, although it took a couple of attempts.

### Summary of approach

I didn’t end up taking any of the approaches I originally contemplated. Instead, my approach involved:

- Creating the new partition scheme on the new SSDs (EFI boot partition plus root partition)
- Installing the UEFI bootloaders on the EFI boot partitions
- Creating a RAID 1 array on the root partitions
- Creating an LVM physical volume using the RAID 1 array and creating an LVM volume group using that volume
- Creating an LVM root logical volume on that volume group
- Copying the contents of the root partition from the old SSDs to the new SSDs
- Creating an LVM swap logical volume on the volume group on the RAID 1 array
- Tidying up

My first attempt involved manually creating the partitions and manually installing the UEFI bootloaders on those partitions. After a few minor missteps along the way, that ended up with a bootable system on the new SSDs, but using the wrong bootloader (the fallback `BOOTX64.EFI` rather than the Ubuntu `grubx64.efi` or `shimx64.efi` bootloader).

It’s possible that I could have fixed this by implementing step 27 below, but that was a step I didn’t discover until implementing my second attempt. But see now the addendum to this answer.

So I started the whole process afresh.

The second attempt involved using the Ubuntu Live USB to perform a fresh install on one of the new SSDs (with my new partition scheme, but with no RAID or LVM). I figured that this would give me an EFI boot partition that reflected the Ubuntu default (size, contents).

This approach also gave me the opportunity to note what parameters a default install included in `/etc/fstab`, so I could properly replicate that on my new install.

Once the default install was completed by the Ubuntu Live USB, I copied the EFI boot partition to the other SSD. I then removed the installed root partition and replaced it with a new one, to wipe the installed OS. I then replicated that partition on the other SSD, and proceeded with the rest of my steps (creating the RAID array, etc).

As you will see, the result of this was a system that didn’t initially boot, but I managed to rescue it from `grub` and now all is well.

Read on for the detailed steps. I must admit that to some degree those steps are a bit of a reconstruction of what I did, as I had a few little twists along the way, but fundamentally what I have outlined below is an accurate reflection of the substance of what I did.

### References

In preparing for and implementing my two attempts, I had reference to a few tutorials, including in particular:

- [Install Ubuntu 18.04 desktop with RAID 1 and LVM on machine with UEFI BIOS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1066028/install-ubuntu-18-04-desktop-with-raid-1-and-lvm-on-machine-with-uefi-bios)
- [How to install Ubuntu 14.04/16.04 64-bit with a dual-boot RAID 1 partition on an UEFI/GPT system?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/660023/how-to-install-ubuntu-14-04-16-04-64-bit-with-a-dual-boot-raid-1-partition-on-an)
- [Which commands to convert a Ubuntu BIOS install to EFI/UEFI without boot-repair on single boot hardware?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/509423/which-commands-to-convert-a-ubuntu-bios-install-to-efi-uefi-without-boot-repair)
- https://serverfault.com/questions/963178/how-do-i-convert-my-linux-disk-from-mbr-to-gpt-with-uefi
- https://www.linux.com/tutorials/how-rescue-non-booting-grub-2-linux/

None exactly matched my use case, and some of the steps outlined actually gave me problems, but they did help in various ways.

### All the details

To set the scene:

- My install is Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
- My old install was on `/dev/md0`, with a swap partition on `/dev/md1`, both on my old SSDs
- I also had a RAID 6 data array (`/dev/md2`) on separate HDDs, which I wanted to preserve with the new install
- My new SSDs were`/dev/nvme0n1` and `/dev/nvme1n1`

Now for the steps:

**Step 1**

This first step I didn’t actually do, but in hindsight it may have helped. It involves preparing my old Ubuntu install (the one I would eventually copy over) by installing some packages that would be needed when running under UEFI. So, when booted into my old install:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install grub-efi-amd64 efibootmgr
```

**Step 2**

Before proceeding, I disabled the swap partition on the old install, just to avoid any legacy settings being carried over when the root partition contents were copied. I'm not sure whether that would have been an actual issue, but wanted to be sure:

```
$ sudo swapoff /dev/md1
```

I then updated `/etc/fstab` in my favourite text editor to comment out the swap entry, and then:

```
$ sudo mount -a
```

**Step 3**

Then I booted into the Ubuntu Live USB (the Desktop version, not the Server version, although my install is Server) in UEFI mode, and selected ‘Install Ubuntu’. You may need to adjust your mobo firmware settings to ensure you boot in UEFI mode.

I suppose I could have used the Server version for this step as well, but given I needed the Desktop version for later steps I decided to keep things simple.

I chose the guided install, selecting to use my first new SSD (`/dev/nvme0n1`) and to install using the entire drive. I did not set up RAID or LVM. This resulted in (a) an EFI boot partition, and (b) a root partition, taking up the rest of the drive, on which Ubuntu Desktop was installed.

**Step 4**

With that done, I rebooted into the Ubuntu Live USB in UEFI mode, this time selecting ‘Try Ubuntu without installing’. You can test that you are in UEFI mode by opening a terminal (Ctrl-Alt-T) and running:

```
$ ls /sys/firmware/efi
```

If this shows a number of files, you are in UEFI mode.

**Step 5**

While at the terminal prompt, I upgraded Ubuntu Live and installed required packages:

```
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
$ sudo apt-get install -y mdadm
```

**Step 6**

I then checked the partition scheme of the new install so that I could properly replicate it on the other SSD:

```
$ sudo parted /dev/nvme0n1
(parted) unit MiB print
Model: Samsung SSD 970 EVO Plus 500GB (nvme)
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 476940MiB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start    End        Size       File system  Name                  Flags
 1      1.00MiB  513MiB     512MiB     fat32        EFI System Partition  boot, esp
 2      513MiB   476939MiB  476426MiB  ext4         

(parted) quit
```

This showed that the default EFI partition was 512 MiB in size, starting 1 MiB from the beginning of the drive, with a FAT32 filesystem.

**Step 7**

I then also checked the default mount parameters in `/etc/fstab` (UUIDs masked below as 'NUMBER'):

```
$ sudo mkdir -p /mnt/newroot
$ sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p2 /mnt/newroot
$ cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
## / was on /dev/nvme0n1p2 during installation

UUID=NUMBER /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1

# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation

UUID=NUMBER  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1

/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0

$ sudo umount /mnt/newroot
```

I took a note of the parameters so that I could replicate them later.

**Step 8**

I then deleted the installed root partition on my first SSD, to remove the Desktop install, and created a fresh partition (same size) in its place. Note that I didn't create it with any filesystem type given that a RAID array and LVM volume group would be overlaid on top:

```
$ sudo parted -a optimal /dev/nvme0n1
(parted) rm
Partition number? 2
(parted) mkpart primary 513MiB 100%
(parted) name 2 "Ubuntu Filesystem"
(parted) align-check optimal 2
(parted) set 2 raid on
```

**Step 9**

While still in the parted interactive prompt, I then selected the other new SSD (`/dev/nvme1n1`) to replicate the partition scheme:

```
(parted) select /dev/nvme1n1
(parted) mklabel gpt
(parted) mkpart primary fat32 1MiB 513MiB
(parted) set 1 esp on
(parted) set 1 boot on
(parted) mkpart primary 513MiB 100%
(parted) name 2 "Ubuntu Filesystem"
(parted) align-check optimal 2
(parted) set 2 raid on
(parted) unit MiB print
Model: Samsung SSD 970 EVO Plus 500GB (nvme)
Disk /dev/nvme1n1: 476940MiB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start    End        Size       File system  Name                  Flags
 1      1.00MiB  513MiB     512MiB     fat32        EFI System Partition  boot, esp
 2      513MiB   476939MiB  476426MiB  ext4         Ubuntu Filesystem     raid

(parted) quit
```

**Step 10**

I then created a RAID 1 array on the root partitions, `/dev/nvme0n1p2` and `/dev/nvme1n1p2`. I called it `/dev/md3` to distinguish it from the RAID arrays already created under my old system and to avoid naming conflicts during the migration, with the aim of renaming it later when the new system was up and running:

```
$ sudo mdadm --create --bitmap=internal /dev/md3 --level=1 --raid-devices=2 /dev/nvme0n1p2 /dev/nvme1n1p2
```

I waited until the RAID array had finished syncing before proceeding, by checking:

```
$ cat /proc/mdstat
```

**Step 11**

I then created an LVM physical volume out of the RAID 1 array, with a single volume group (called `vgmain`) using that physical volume, and then an LVM root logical volume (called `lvroot` and with size of 100 GiB) on that volume group:

```
$ sudo pvcreate /dev/md3
$ sudo vgcreate vgmain /dev/md3
$ sudo lvcreate -L 100G -n lvroot vgmain
```

**Step 12**

I then created an EXT4 filesystem on the root logical volume:

```
$ sudo mkfs.ext4 -b 4096 -E stride=128,stripe-width=256 /dev/vgmain/lvroot
```

**Step 13**

At this point I assembled the old RAID devices so that my old root partition (`/dev/md0`) was available to copy data from. Obviously to do this my old SSDs still had to be connected and powered up:

```
$ sudo mdadm --assemble --scan
```

**Step 14**

Once assembled, I mounted the old root partition:

```
$ sudo mkdir -p /mnt/oldroot
$ sudo mount /dev/md0 /mnt/oldroot
```

**Step 15**

I also mounted the new root partition (remember the mountpoint had been created previously in step 7):

```
$ sudo mount /dev/vgmain/lvroot /mnt/newroot
```

**Step 16**

Now I could copy the contents of the old root partition to the new one:

```
$ sudo rsync -axHAX --progress /mnt/oldroot/ /mnt/newroot
```

**Step 17**

Once completed, the old root partition could be unmounted and the old RAID array stopped:

```
$ sudo umount /mnt/oldroot
$ sudo mdadm --stop /dev/md0
```

**Step 18**

A digression now. In hindsight the boot issue I encountered at the end might have been avoidable if I had performed step 27 at this point in time. To do so, I would have done the following:

```
$ sudo mkdir -p /mnt/newroot/boot/efi
$ sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p1 /mnt/newroot/boot/efi
$ for d in /dev /dev/pts /sys /proc; do sudo mount -B $d /mnt/newroot$d; done
$ sudo chroot /mnt/newroot
# grub-install
# update-grub
# umount /dev/nvme0n1p1
```

I'm not sure if that would have fixed the issue encountered later, but there it is. But see now the addendum to this answer.

**Step 19**

Back to what I actually did. Having copied over the contents of the old root partition to the new root partition (which of course were mirrored in the RAID 1 array), I needed to copy the EFI boot partition contents from the first SSD to the second SSD:

```
$ sudo dd if=/dev/nvme0n1p1 of=/dev/nvme1n1p1
```

To check that this was successful, I checked that the UUID on each was the same after completion:

```
$ sudo blkid
```

**Step 20**

For completeness I also wanted to get the second SSD into the boot chain, to ensure that I could happily boot from either SSD. At this stage the new root partition was still mounted, but I needed to mount other directories from the Ubuntu Live USB as well (I would not have had to mount those here if I had implemented step 18):

```
$ for d in /dev /dev/pts /sys /proc; do sudo mount -B $d /mnt/newroot$d; done
$ sudo chroot /mnt/newroot
# efibootmgr -v

## Comment: The above command showed me the file entry for "ubuntu", which in my case was
## \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi (I could have also used \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi).
## I then used that in the next command

# efibootmgr -c -d /dev/nvme1n1 -p 1 -L ubuntu -l '\EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi'
```

Obviously, the effect of a `chroot` to the new SSDs was that I entered that environment as if I was booted into it, so commands I ran while in the jail were executed on the SSDs, rather than on the Ubuntu Live USB. And in a `chroot` jail, commands are run as root (as indicated by the ‘#’ prompt), so `sudo` is not required. Although of course given that the SSDs were not actually booted, I had to mount some key directories from the Ubuntu Live USB to give me the required functionality.

(As an aside, I have to note that, as I had not actually done step 1, when I attempted to run `efibootmgr` I found it wasn't installed, because I had copied across my legacy install which was a MBR/BIOS installation. So I had to install it at this stage. And to do so, I found I also need to mount `/run` from the Ubuntu Live USB, to give me internet access. I also installed `grub-efi-amd64`.)

**Step 21**

I also checked that the boot order was correct, ie that `/dev/nvme0n1p1` was first in the boot chain, and `/dev/nvme1n1p1` was second, by checking the details returned by `efibootmgr -v`. If necessary, the order can fixed by running the following command with the 4 digit code for each relevant disk or partition, in the order required, for example:

```
# efibootmgr -o 0000,0001,0002,0005,0004
```

**Step 22**

I then updated `/etc/fstab` with my favourite text editor to include the new UUIDs for the root mountpoint and the`/boot/efi` mountpoint (as determined from `blkid`). I used the parameters from step 7, adding `noatime` to the root mountpoint (consistent with my old installation).

Of course I kept the mountpoint entry for my old data RAID 6 array, as that would continue to be used with the new install, as well as a mountpoint securing `/tmp`.

**Step 23**

The configuration details for mdadm on the new SSDs also needed to be updated, which I did by adding the details for the new array `/dev/md3` via the command below, and then manually editing `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf` with my text editor to ensure that the legacy entries for the old `/dev/md0` and `/dev/md1` were removed:

```
# mdadm --examine --scan >> /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf
```

Once the configuration file was cleaned up, I ran:

```
# update-initramfs -u
```

**Step 24**

I was essentially done at this point (or so I thought). So for a clean completion, I exited from `chroot` and unmounted everything:

```
# exit
$ for d in /dev /dev/pts /sys /proc; do sudo umount /mnt/newroot$d; done
$ sudo umount /mnt/newroot
```

**Step 25**

Finally, the moment of truth - I removed the Ubuntu Live USB, and rebooted the system, checking in my mobo firmware that the boot order had my first new SSD at the top, so that I would boot from `/dev/nvme0n1p1`. If necessary, you can check when booted which drive has been booted from, by running `efibootmgr -v`.

**Step 26**

At this point, though, I had my boot issue. The system wouldn't boot, and stopped at the `grub` prompt. To fix this, I did the following at the prompt:

```
grub> ls

## Comment: The above command showed me the available partitions and directories, so I knew
## what my root partition was called and could use it in the next command

grub> set root=(lvm/vgmain-lvroot)
grub> linux /vmlinuz root=/dev/mapper/vgmain-lvroot
grub> initrd /initrd.img
grub> boot
```

**Step 27**

Doing this got me booted into the new SSDs. At that point, I ran the following, which might not have been necessary if I had done these at step 18:

```
$ sudo grub-install
$ sudo update-grub
```

I found that after running these commands, the size of `grubx64.efi` in `/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu` changed, so it appears there was something amiss with the original bootloader installation. But see now the addendum to this answer.

**Step 28**

I then repeated the relevant commands in steps 19 and 20 to copy the contents of the updated EFI boot partition from `/dev/nvme0n1p1` to `/dev/nvme1n1p1`, and to update the boot chain. If you find you have legacy entries that also need to be deleted, use:

```
$ sudo efibootmgr -b 0003 -B  # Eg to delete entry Boot0003
```

**Step 29**

Finally I re-created my swap partition, this time as an LVM logical volume:

```
$ sudo lvcreate -L 16G -n lvswap vgmain
$ sudo mkswap /dev/vgmain/lvswap
$ sudo swapon /dev/vgmain/lvswap
```

And updated `/etc/fstab` with the relevant UUID and the parameters determined in step 7:

```
UUID=NUMBER none    swap    sw  0   0
```

And that was it! I have now a fully migrated and functioning system. I will eventually rename my new RAID 1 to `md0` (for OCD reasons only), but that is for another day.

### Addendum

**Item 1**

The preparatory tutorials I studied before attempting the migration said that Secure Boot should be disabled on the mobo firmware before starting. I did not do that, as I found that my mobo (Asus) made it difficult to do so (I have since researched it and found it can be done by deleting the Secure Boot keys). It’s possible that my boot issues were caused by Secure Boot still being operative.

**Item 2**

You will find when booting your migrated system in UEFI mode that it pauses for 30 seconds at the grub menu before proceeding. This is apparently to give the user time to access the menu, as in certain circumstances it may otherwise become inaccessible. If you are annoyed by the additional delay to the boot time, you can reduce this by adding the following to `/etc/default/grub`:

```
GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT=5  # Eg to reduce to five seconds
```

Don’t reduce it to zero. And then:

```
$ sudo update-grub
```